# Какую среду разработк/редактор кода выбрать для разработки на C/C++ на. Mac M1?

Tags: c++, c, ide

Хочется чего-то легковесного и быстрого в настройке, так чтобы скачать и начать писать. До этого использовал Clion, но программа довольно громоздкая и тяжелая в настройке. Если как таковых альтернатив нет, то не могли бы вы скинуть ссылку с подробной инструкцией настройки этой IDE именно на моем ноутбуке.

Answer (score -2):

Безусловно юзай Visual Studio 2017. Обьясняю почему:
Она полна полезных функций(например автоформатирование кода после завершения строки), если я правильно понял, то ты начинающий в C++, VS показывает на твои синтаксические ошибки, в VS один из самых удобных отладчиков(после него в LION не хватает некоторых функций), больше туториалов для работы с ним.

Comment: Почему-то именно старую 17-ую. И почему-то на маке (есть какой-то visual studio for mac, но гугл подсказывает, что вроде бы он не для С++).

Comment: Потому что 2022 часто "сбивает с ног новичков", как по мне она перенасыщенна ненужными для неопытных пользователей, прекрасно с таким же успехом можно и на 19, но я все же советую именно 17(т.к. она оптимальнее )